# Attribute format specifier warning . Need some clarification

Tags: c, gcc, printf, string-formatting

I am confused about the attribute format specifier in C. I came across a warning when compiling some code. Here is the warning:

warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Here is a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test (int a, int b, const char* ax, const char* bx)__attribute__((format (printf, 3, 0)));
int main()
{
    char * a = "abc";
    char* b = "cde";
    test(1,2,NULL,NULL); /*produces warning*/
    test(1,2,a,NULL); /* does not produce warning */
}  
void test(int a, int b, const char* ax, const char* bx)
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

And here is output:

```
gcc -o asn.o test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:5: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     test(1,2,NULL,NULL); /*produces warning*/
     ^~~~
```

The warning is produced whenever the following conditions are true (based on experimentation):

1. The format to be checked is a NULL.
2. A zero is passed in the third argument for the attribute format specifier
3. The format is not the last argument in the function.

The following code seems to work fine which makes me believe that NULL is a valid string since it is only checking for consistency:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test (int a, int b, const char* ax)__attribute__((format (printf, 3, 0)));
int main()
{
    char * a = "abc";
    char* b = "cde";
    test(1,2,NULL);
    test(1,2,a);
}  
void test(int a, int b, const char* ax)
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

Can someone explain the behavior to me? Does it have to do with NULL or zero in the attribute format specifier? I am using gcc 7.2.0

EDIT:

Some more information from the discussions. The issue here is that this is not a variadic function and hence the third argument is passed as zero. The documentation mentions this

> For functions where the arguments are not available to be checked (such as vprintf), specify the third parameter as zero.

Since NULL is a "consistent" string I would believe it should not issue warnings. Also just to reiterate this is not my code but from a well-known library.

EDIT 2:

Trying a few more things I came across the vsnprintf  which uses a similar signature. Passing NULL to the format string leads to three warnings

```
warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 3) [-Wnonnull]
   vsnprintf (buffer,256,NULL, args);
   ^~~~~~~~~
testvsn.c:10:31: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
   vsnprintf (buffer,256,NULL, args);
                               ^~~~
testvsn.c:10:3: warning: null format string [-Wformat-truncation=]
   vsnprintf (buffer,256,NULL, args);
```

At this point, I believe that NULL passed as a string is just undefined behavior or function using the definition as above should not allow NULL strings. Will appreciate if someone has concrete answers though.

Comment: Why do you have `__attribute__` on the end of that signature? That seems to be the source of your problem.

Comment: @tadman Switching it does not remove the warning. This is a sample code derived from a library. So I was just replicating them

Comment: Did you intentionally omit the `*/` from line 7 ? Also do you have `gcc` aliased to `gcc -Wall` or something? I get no warnings unless I also use a warning switch.

Comment: @M.M That was a typo. I did not use any warning switch though. What version of gcc were you using?

Comment: I tried several different versions of gcc, none warned unless warning switches were provided

Comment: It seems `gcc` provided with Ubuntu by default carries the `-Wformat` and `Wformat-security` options

Answer (score 1):

For a `printf` family function, `NULL` is not a valid format string. It would cause undefined behaviour to pass `NULL` as format string to the Standard Library functions.

The evidence you have posted suggests that gcc does not seem to support the behaviour you hoped for, i.e. "only do format checking if the argument was non-NULL".

Perhaps you could file a bug report, the "too many arguments for format" message is certainly nonsense. I would guess that it assumes `vprintf` mode due to the last argument of `0` but it got confused since there wasn't actually a `va_list` argument somewhere.

Note that using a variable for the format string (i.e. `a`) means that the string cannot be checked anyway. It only checks cases where the format string is a string literal; it doesn't attempt to do any static analysis to trace the source of the variable.  You can test this out by doing `char *a = "%y"; test(1,2,a,NULL);` versus `test(1,2,"%y",NULL);`.

Answer (score -3):

If I remove the `__attribute__` cruft the warning goes away using GCC 7.2.1. If I leave it in with `-Wformat -Wformat-extra-args` it stays.

You're specifying that `test` takes a format string in position 3 and then takes zero additional arguments. This is of course completely contradictory to your function.

The `printf` attribute directive is how GCC raises warnings for *varargs* type functions where you need to verify a certain number of arguments have been passed in, something you must do at runtime otherwise. It's not something you're doing, so you shouldn't use that directive.

Whenever you encounter something unfamiliar like this take time to [read the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to better understand their purpose before blindly using them.

Short answer: Don't use `__attribute__` without a reason.

Comment: I di dread the documentation and here is from the documentation," For functions where the arguments are not available to be checked (such as vprintf), specify the third parameter as zero. In this case, the compiler only checks the format string for consistency." So the third argument is not for "zero additional arguments". Also, as I said I am not writing this code but replicating from a well know library.

Comment: You're not passing in a format string, but you're telling the compiler you are, and in the process of verifying that string it found zero placeholders which means there should be zero arguments after the format string. Regardless, this attribute has no place being attached to this particular function.

Comment: I don't get your edited answer. In the second sample, the format string is not NULL. It "abc". I am confused what is the use of zero as the third argument in the attribute argument specifier. What does it help achieve? Also from a previous comment, "here should be zero arguments after the format string". I don't see anywhere where this is mentioned. The third argument as zero in the attribute format specifier does NOT specify that there will be zero arguments.

Comment: @ArulMoondra http://unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html: `__attribute__((format(printf,m,n)))` 'The (m) is the number of the "format string" parameter, and (n) is the number of the first variadic parameter.'

Comment: @ChristianGibbons For a function that takes variadic arguments yes, but this function does not. The "n" is hence zero.The documentation, "For functions where the arguments are not available to be checked (such as vprintf), specify the third parameter as zero. In this case, the compiler only checks the format string for consistency." Also NULL is a consistent string as demonstrated by the second sample function I provided.

Comment: You're passing `a` through on the second instance, my edit missed that. Still, I think we're splitting hairs here. The facts remain: the `__attribute__` declaration is inappropriate here as there's no *varargs* and the function signature does not take in a template argument. You're not supposed to stick that on any function that uses `printf`, you should put it **only** on functions that take a template *and* variable arguments.

Comment: @tadman I don't think it is inappropriate since, 1.The documentation mentions the use case as in vprintf and 2. the sample code I provided in the second sample works fine.

Comment: You're not using `vprintf`, it's not appropriate. I have no idea why you're fighting the obvious here. Just because the warning doesn't trigger doesn't mean the attribute is necessary or warranted.

Comment: I am fighting because this is a libxml2 code and it has worked for countless people without errors. I am not sure why they used it there but there is something obvious that I don't understand here and hence the question.

Comment: This attribute is for functions which want to behave like `printf` does and produce warnings when template arguments have placeholders but the values aren't supplied. Your function has none of these characteristics.

Comment: @tadman related, can you explain to me what does the documentation mean when it says, "will only check the string for consistency" Documentation source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes

Comment: Presumably that means that things like `%z` or `%$` will be flagged as invalid since it's not a placeholder `printf` understands.